# how to svn diff between a working copy and an unrelated branch

Tags: svn, merge, branch, diff

Here is the scenario:

User 1

1. create branches/X
2. svn checkout branches/X to local machine
3. modify file.txt
4. commit changes

Another user, User 2,

1. create branches/Y
2. svn checkout branches/Y to his local machine
3. merge branches/X to local machine    (and thus merges file.txt into branches/Y)
4. use svn diff to verify that the changes to file.txt in the local copy of branches/Y succeeded before committing the change.

Since svn diff can not compare the local working copy to that of a URL, step 4 of User 2 is impossible to do without first committing the change to branches/Y.
But this defeats the whole purpose of verifying that a merge has produced the correct results before committing the merge changes.

I have googled for this, but have not found any usable solution.
Only recommended solution is to check out branches/X so that svn can compare two paths.
Since the merge changes have not been checked in yet, I can not use svn diff with two URL's.

It is impractical, not to mention time consuming and tedious, to checkout both branches/X and branches/Y just so that I can perform a diff.

Is there any way to compare the merged changes in a local working copy, which have not been committed yet, with those from the merge branch?

Comment: It seems to me that between (2)(svn checkout Y) and (3)(svn merge X), if there are changes in Y / an existing file `file.txt`, you should _commit_ Y before _merging_ X to it, making it perfectly possible to just do a `svn diff ` / `svn diff -rHEAD` on the checkout.

Comment: There is no question... Cannot understand what your problem is..

Comment: There are no local changes to file.txt in branches/Y.  Therefore, there is nothing to commit.  file.txt is only modified by merging in the version from branches/X.  I need to compare the resulting file.txt generated by subversion's merge with the original copy in branches/X to confirm that subversion merged in the changes correctly before committing those changes to my local working copy, which is branches/Y.

Answer (score 7):

Johan Corveleyn provided me with the answer.  I'm posting it here so that others can see the answer.

svn diff can indeed compare a working copy file on your local path with another version in the repository, and hence referenced via a URL.  Below is the syntax:

```
svn diff --old=http://repository/branches/X/file.txt --new=file.txt
```